# Consider a function on a domain

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

Consider the function g(x) = x
2 −2x+ 3 on the domain D = (1, 3).

I'm a bit confused on how to approach this question. First of all, does the domain mean I have to restrict the x value of the quadratic to the domain? I think that's all I need to help me get through this question, I can't seem to find it in my notes. Thanks!

Also this is kind of a stupid question but what kind of maths is this sort of question considered to be?

Comment: Okay, I've considered the function, is there anything else to the question?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, but I just wanted to know if considering a function on the domain means I have to only consider the part that is included in the domain.

Comment: Oh. I would it assume it means to consider the function only on that domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain of a function is the set of values for which the function is defined. So with your domain of $D = (1,3)$, $f(x)$ is defined for all values of $x$ in between, but not including, $1$ and $3$. If the domain was instead $[1,3]$, then you'd include $1,3$ in the possible values of $x$. For future reference, $D = (a, b)$ means all values of $x$ such that $a < x < b$, while $[a,b]$ means all values of $x$ such that $a \leq x \leq b$.

I'm not sure what the question is asking, but if you're asked to graph $f(x)$ on the given domain, then simply graph $f(x)$ for the values of $x$ it takes on in the domain.